# Embedding YouTube problem!

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web

This question seems to be lame but here it is:

I have a simple ASP.NET web page. I am integrating a YouTube Page. As I got the code from YouTube webpage:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7Zo1xE5a4vQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I am including this into my `<div>` tag it is not showing in my webpage when I am running in my localhost. Here is my `<div>` code where I am integrating YouTube:

```
<div id="video">
        <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" 
                src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7Zo1xE5a4vQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen 
                style="height: 332px"></iframe>
           </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong! Check the HTML of your output - maybe use the inspector in Google Chrome (or Firebug or the debugger in IE) to find out why the iframe is not shown.

Comment: Is there any CSS attached to div#video?

Comment: I've copied your code and pasted it into a page - works fine. have you followed @Curt's suggestion and seen if there is some CSS that is hiding your div?

Try adding some text or something inside the div but outside the iframe tag and see if that is visible.